# Авторские права

Tags: юридические-аспекты

Что делать если захотел создать игру по мотивам аниме. Нужно ли покупать авторские прова.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не имеет отношения ни к программированию, ни к системному администрированию, а является скорее юридическим.

Comment: Смена метки, к сожалению, не делает вопрос тематичным для сайта. Ознакомьтесь со справкой: ["На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)